# Vertically align content in inline-block list items

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display an unordered list horizontally. In each list item, I have an anchor tag with an image, that I'd like to display vertically aligned in the list item. Here's my

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="50" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="50" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="50" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 93px;
}

ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 110px;
    height: 93px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zgxHB/1/

Try using `display: table-cell;` instead of `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Hi. I'm curious about your approach versus the one @Kyle Sevenoaks suggests below (`float: left`.)

Any recommendation as which one is better? Both seem to achieve the same visual effect, but I was just wondering. TIA.

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene, table-cell allows for the vertical alignment as well as the horizontal. http://jsfiddle.net/zgxHB/20/ , a view of the float solution.

Comment: Thanks @JoeTuskan. So if you don't care about vertical alignment, both ways are interchangeable?

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene, if you don't need vertical alignment use float as it is widely understood.

Answer (score 6):

Try floating the li's left. This will display them in a horizontal line and retain their block status

Answer (score 1):

display:inline-block; treats element as if they inline level, which means any whitespace in your markup is displayed when the page is rendered.

TRY:

```
<ul><li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="50" />
        </a>
    </li><li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="50" />
        </a>
    </li><li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="50" />
        </a>
</li></ul>
```

OR:

```
<ul><!--
    --><li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="50" />
        </a>
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="50" />
        </a>
    </li><!--
    --><li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="" height="50" width="50" />
        </a>
    </li><!--
--></ul>
```